# Asset pipeline force js.erb recompiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

My js.erb files are not being regenerated even when I restart the development server. Is there a way for me to force the asset pipeline to regenerate all of the javascript assets every time I restart the server?

If I change the actual .js.erb source file then it recompiles fine, but the code pulls from the database, reading seeded data that could change between server restarts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Late call here, but having had this problem all over the place, and being REALLY annoyed by it, dug in a bit.  Here's my solution:

On restarting your server, `rm -rf tmp/cache/*`

That will blow away the SCSS and other cached assets, and force a recompile.

You could run `rake assets:clean` instead if you prefer or are using Rake to restart your server.

Obviously, doing this slows server restart by a bit, but may be worth it for the removal of this major pain point...

Answer (score 1):

Think of any ruby you execute within the asset pipeline as happening before your server starts up, since that's effectively what happens in production with the asset precompile step (and in development it'll refresh if the files change, as you've described).  In this case you'd want to refactor that code into a controller and something in your app/views directory (html.erb/js.erb) so that your code gets run on every request.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting my question. We will restart the server if the seed data that the JS depends on ever changes (it's static stuff like country => state mappings). My problem is that *even on server restarts* in dev the JS is not regenerated.  I have to change the actual source file (guessing it's doing some kind of hashing) for it to pick it up.

Comment: Yeah -- I grok it now.  Do you have config.assets.debug set to true in your development env?  Assuming that's not it you might check out https://github.com/wavii/rails-dev-tweaks for some clues to what rails is doing under the hood, though I don't think it'll solve your problem out of the box since it's geared towards compiling assets less often.

Comment: yea `config.assets.debug` is set, thanks for the resource I'll do some more digging